# Moving /boot to a usb key

Tags: boot, usb-drive

How do I move the existing /boot partion of a 14.04 root encrypted installation to a usb key?

Comment: Do you want /boot (and grub_) or just grub boot loader in MBR of external drive? You can do either one. It would be just like moving /home. You need to create a new partition on flash drive and copy files from old /boot to new one. Then reinstall grub to use new UUID and update fstab to use new partition for /boot. This is moving /home but very similar other than reinstall of grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: Please be aware that encrypting `/boot` and physically removing it from your computer, doesn't prevent people from accessing the rest of the data on the internal drive(s).

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

In a normal session:

Insert the usb stick.

Open a terminal. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>.

Identify the usb-stick, suppose is /dev/sdc1, umount it:

```
sudo -i
fdisk -l
umount /dev/sdc1
```

Load gparted

```
gparted
```

Delete a patition, create an ext4 partition, apply the changes and close gparted

You must mount the new /boot partition, suppose is new ext4 /dev/sdc1 on a temporary directory, suppose is /media/newboot to copy files to it the original /boot.

Run it:

You create the temporary directory

```
 mkdir /media/newboot
```

Umount and mount partition

```
umount /dev/sdc1 
mount /dev/sdc1 /media/newboot
```

To copy files:

```
cd /boot
cp -ax . /media/newboot
```

This last line is the only one used to clone, attention "." the end.

Now mount the new /boot previous rename the /boot partition.

```
cd /
mv /boot /boot.old
mkdir /boot
umount /dev/sdc1
mount /dev/sdc1 /boot
```

Now you have to find the UUID of the partition and edit the /etc/fstab file to mount the partition at startup.

```
blkid /dev/sdc1
nano /etc/fstab
```

And you add these lines at the end with that reported blkid UUID.

```
# /dev/sdc1 was /boot
UUID=c676ae51-cb6f-4c0e-b4a9-76850aafa1d6  /boot ext4 errors=remount-ro  0  1
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

```
update-grub
```

Restarting have everything working exactly the same, but with other partitions.

Once everything is working well, delete the /boot.old and /media/newboot

```
sudo -i
rm /boot.old
rm /media/newboot
```

Note:You should be aware that without the usb-stick the system will be unusable.